# Subscript out of range error while generating chart excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating a line chart with data from a Pivot Table. The chart gets generated but it throws an error 'Subscript out of range' in the below code.

> ```
> .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("PivotData").Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(29, 8))
> ```

Here is my code

```
Dim co1 As ChartObject
Set co1 = PivotDays.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Cells(2, 11).Left, Width:=Range("b2:h2").Width, _
Top:=Cells(21, 2).Top, Height:=Range("b2:b18").Height)


    With co1.Chart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="PivotDays"
        '.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("PivotData").Range("A5:H28")
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("PivotData").Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(29, 8))
    End With
```

I could not figure out why? Any suggestions please

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely due to the fact that the sheet `PivotData` is not the active sheet. Anyway dont count on the active sheet, qualify the `Cells`.

```
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("PivotData").Range(Sheets("PivotData").Cells(5, 1), Sheets("PivotData").Cells(29, 8))
```

Simpler, you can provide addresses instead:

```
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("PivotData").Range("A5:H29")
```